# Probability of particular order of occurrence of independent exponential distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

So I have three independent Poisson processes $X, Y, Z$ with $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3$ respectively as the rate parameters. I'm interested in the probability that the first event comes from $X$, the second from $Y$ and the third from $Z$ (in that order exactly).

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Integrate the joint density over $\{(x,y,z): x<y<z\}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Comment:** Possible hints:

(1) If $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda_3,$ then by symmetry the answer is $1/6.$

This can be illustrated by a simulation of $10^6$ iterations in which we ask whether $X = \min(X,Y,Z)$ and
$Z = \max(X,Y,Z).$ (With a million iterations, one can
expect two or three place accuracy.)

```
lam.1 = 1; lam.2=1; lam.3=1; m = 10^6
set.seed(2020)
x = rexp(m,lam.1); y = rexp(m,lam.2); z=rexp(m,lam.3)
v = pmin(x,y,z); w = pmax(x,y,z)
mean(x==v & z==w)
[1] 0.166596  # aprx 1/6
```

(2) Here is a simulation for unequal $\lambda_i.$

```
lam.1 = 1; lam.2=2; lam.3=3; m = 10^6
set.seed(2020)
x = rexp(m,lam.1); y = rexp(m,lam.2);  z=rexp(m,lam.3)
v = pmin(x,y,z);  w = pmax(x,y,z)
mean(x==v & z==w)
[1] 0.066714
```

[Even if this doesn't help you see how to get a
general analytic solution, you can check your
analytic solution against these results.]

(3) Maybe start by finding $P(X<Y).$